# generate textboxes based on number enter by user

Tags: javascript, html

I want when a user enter number in the textbox and click set, textboxes appear based on the number he entered and this what I come up with but it is not working please help

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function generate(){
var a=parseInt(document.getElementById("nochapter").value);
for (i=0;i<=a,i++){
document.getElementById("ch").innerHTML="<input type='text' >"}}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Prepare new assessment</h1>
<form>
No. of Chapter included <input type="text" id="nochapter" > 
<input type ="button" value="set" onclick="generate()">

<div id="ch"></div>
```

Comment: Are you okay using jQuery or do you want to use pure JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be like this.
Is better append an input element to the div.

```
<head>
    <script>
    function generate() {

        var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("nochapter").value);
        var ch = document.getElementById("ch");

        for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            ch.appendChild(input);
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1> Prepare new assessment</h1>
    <form>
        No. of Chapter included
        <input type="text" id="nochapter" />
        <input type="button" value="set" onclick="generate()" />
        <div id="ch"></div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is small glitch in your written code

**for (i=0;i<=a,i++) --> for (i=0;i<=a;i++)**

even if you change that it will generate only one text box because you are replacing innerHTML for every iteration. so prepare the string separately based on no of iteration and assign it to innerrHTML. it should work.